# Trigger Javascript if scrolling down and on a certain width size

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a javascript that changes a header color when scrolling down 150px. I would also want it to not trigger if the webpage is adjusted to a certain width (991px).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 150 && width > 991px) {
        $(".bg-header").css("background-color" , "rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)");
      }

      else{
          $(".bg-header").css("background-color" , "transparent");
      }
  })
})
```

What's the equivalent of `(window).scrollTop()` but for the page width?

Comment: where does the `width` variable come from? also, to compare with a value, you should omit the unit (px)

Comment: my bad let me elaborate more

Comment: im looking for the equivalent of scrollTop() but for the page width

Comment: `window.innerWidth`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed version of your codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();
    if (scroll > 150 && width > 991) {
        $(".bg-header").css("background-color" , "rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)");
    } else{
        $(".bg-header").css("background-color" , "transparent");
    }
  });
});
```

As mentioned in the comment above, if you want to compare the value, you should omit the unit (px).

Comment: I believe with jQuery you can just use `$(window).width()` right?

Comment: i see that this is right but i realised that the number is not in pixels, how do i check for pixel length?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-jQuery reliant version that should be functionally equivalent to what you're looking for:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var scroll = window.scrollY;

    var header = document.querySelector('.bg-header');
    if (scroll > 150 && width > 991) {
        header.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)";
    }
    else {
        header.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.4)";
    }
});
```